# Laravel form submit giving 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have used bootstrap modal box for submit a form. This is my HTML

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="customerSubmit">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    @if(session('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('success')}}</div>
                    @endif
                    @if(session('error'))
                    <div class="alert alert-error">{{session('error')}}</div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="hpcontact">HP Contact No</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="hpcontact" id="hpcontact" type="text" placeholder="HP Contact No" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="icno">IC No</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="icno" id="icno" type="text" placeholder="Enter IC No" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="homephone">Home Contact No</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="homephone" id="homephone" type="text" placeholder="Enter home contact no" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dob">D.O.B</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="dob" id="dob" type="date" placeholder="Enter DOB" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="officeno">Office No</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="officeno" id="officeno" type="text" placeholder="Enter Office No" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="address">Address</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="address" id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" data-original-title="" title="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addcustomer" type="submit" data-original-title="" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" title="">Add Customer</button>
    <input class="btn btn-light" type="reset" value="Cancel" data-original-title="" title="">
</div>
```

This is the Route for the form submit

```
Route::post('modaluser/add', 'CustomerController@adduser')->name('customer.adduser');
```

This is the controller and the method

```
public function adduser(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    return Response()->json($input);
}
```

And this is the jQuery for the Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','#addcustomer',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/admin/modaluser/add',
            data: $('#customerSubmit').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("some error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the from where i want to submit this https://eu.2e.my/admin/booking/choose. After choose  a package and submit a random number, you can find the "+Add Customer" link in each row. just click in any of them. After that the form will appear. I have given the code above. Now when i submit this, It is giving me 500 error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did the error message say? try to console.log() it so you can know the problem

Comment: It is giving me 500 internal server error in console.

Comment: You can also see in the url. https://eu.2e.my/admin/booking/choose

Comment: What does your server error log say?

Comment: where can i see the error log ?

Comment: I'm not sure but, `return Response()->json($input);` wouldn't the capital `R` be a problem here?  Should it not be `response()` or does the case not matter?

Comment: @Ranjit log files are located in `storage/logs`

Comment: this is what my error log. [2019-12-13 03:26:14] local.ERROR: Method App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CustomerController::adduser does not exist.

Comment: Buut it is already defined in the like     public function adduser(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        return Response()->json($input);
    }

Comment: Your route is defined to use `CustomerController@adduser` but your error messages says it's looking for `Admin\CustomerController@adduser` so something here isn't adding up

Answer (score 1):

ajax url is incorrect

change

```
    url: '/admin/modaluser/add',
```

to

```
url: '{{ url('modaluser/add') }}'
```

or

```
url: '{{ route('customer.adduser') }}'
```

Comment: what is your laravel version

Comment: please switch to developer mode as you can see errors